# Unity running with -parentHWND <HWND> param freezes

Tags: windows, winapi, unity-game-engine, electron, hwnd

I want to open unity game inside electron app. I start it as new node child process with parameter -parentHWND, then i send WM_ACTIVE message with value WA_ACTIVE, to this electron window. I do it by my native node module using winapi.

It works fine on windows 8 and it worked fine half a year ago on win 10, but now I have extreme freezes on unity game on win 10.

I've tried to send continuously WM_ACTIVE message in case that window would somehow become inactive but its not that.

Have somebody idea how to fix that, or at least know something about update of windows 10 which could caused that strange behavior?

Comment: WM_ACTIVE is nothing you are allowed to send. WM_ACTIVE is sent by the OS to your window, when it gets active (i.e. receiving the focus).

Comment: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130412-00/?p=4683) TL;DR: If you have to ask, it probably isn't for you.

Comment: Generally it is behavior described in unity example about embedded window but they use unity game in connection with windows form app. Sending WM_ACTIVE is the advice which I've found in topics about this problem. On Windows 8 it works perfectly and on Windows 10 it worked some time ago also and it was stable.

Comment: The **only** way to construct a reliable cross-process window relationship is, if you control the message loop and window procedure of both participating parties. If you are using libraries (like Windows Forms or Unity), you cannot pull this off in a reliable fashion. The fact that it *appeared* to work previously is due to luck only, not by virtue of being correct code. The short answer is: You cannot do what you have set out to do.